# How will law of large number changes if we have Indepedent but not identically distributed?

Tags: probability, statistics

How will law of large number changes if we have Indepedent but not identically distributed ?

Comment: That depends. If you let $X_i$ be uniformly distributed on $[0, 10^{-10i}]$, I think whatever $n$ you choose, the sum of the $X_i$ up to $n$ looks more or less like a uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$, with some mess at the ends of the interval.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reasonable and  predictable pattern of distributions (each with
a known mean and variance), then the LLN will work.

As a simple example, suppose odd-numbered terms in the sequence are Bernoulli with P(S) = 1/4
and even-numbered terms are Bernoulli with P(S) = 3/4, then the sequence of cumulative averages
converges in probability to 1/2. It would not be difficult to
prove this by finding the distribution of $Y_i = X_o + X_e$
and considering the new sequence $Y_1, Y_2, \dots.$

Some advanced probability books have rules for such more
general versions of the LLN.

*Note:* A related and also interesting problem is whether
you can relax the assumption of independence. Markov dependence
allows for limited kinds of dependence, and a major topic
in the study of Markov processes is to find conditions under
which convergence holds.

The entire field of Markov Chain Monte Carlo simulation, 
much used in applied probability, depends on contriving chains
for which the answer is Yes.